# Can I get my grid to behave like I want without having to manually add in grid-items with Javascript?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.grid-container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background-color: grey;
}

.grid-container2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 75%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background-color: grey;
}

.one {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.two {
  background-color: beige;
}

.three {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container1">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container2">
  <div></div>
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```

Grid-container = GC.
Grid-item = GI.

The first GC successfully allows me to add any number of GIs and have each GI take up an equal amount of space.

At some point (using a media-query) I want the layout to look like I have in GC2 - any number of `background-color`'d GIs equally take up the last 25% of the `width` of their GC. But notice how I have to introduce an empty GI, it's cell spanning 75% of GC `width`, at the start in order to achieve this. To me, this seems annoying as I'd have to use JavaScript. Is there anyway I can achieve what I want just using CSS?

---

EDIT

Just thought of this idea: keep my empty `div` and just set its `display: block/none` when I need it, changing `grid-auto-columns: initial/75%` when I need it too. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes It is possible with Grids itself :) Let me give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo element can help here. Resize the screen to see the result:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background-color: grey;
}

@media (min-width:800px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 75%;
  }
  .grid-container::before {
    content: "";
  }
}

.grid-container :nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.grid-container :nth-child(even) {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to simply use padding since it's supposed to be an empty space:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background-color: grey;
}

@media (min-width:800px) {
  .grid-container {
    padding-left: 75%;
  }
}

.grid-container :nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.grid-container :nth-child(even) {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS-Grid's`  concept `grid-areas` to achieve this in Pure CSS.

**Codepen Link :** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/gOwzdar

```css
.grid-container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background-color: grey;
}

/*  You can use CSS-Grid. Grid-Areas*/
.grid-container2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
  background:#777;
  
  grid-template-areas:
    ". . . . . . .  . . one-2  two-2 three-2"
}

.one,.one-2{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.two,.two-2 {
  background-color: beige;
}

.three,.three-2 {
  background-color: orangered;
}

/* --- CSS-Grids -- */
.one-2{
  grid-area:one-2;
}
.two-2{
  grid-area:two-2;
}
.three-2{
  grid-area:three-2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container1">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container2">
  <div class="one-2">1</div>
  <div class="two-2">2</div>
  <div class="three-2">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One of the requirements of my task is that you can add in any number of GIs and all GIs will take up equal space in the last 25% of GC width. I don't think this achieves that

Comment: Hmmm !!! What you can do is using grid-area-template dynamically in your Javascript without adding any other extra HTML div. I guess you are creating GIs based on some API data. So while you map over the array you can using Javascript style ways to achieve this :)

Comment: For Example As you loop you can add classes dynamically  <div class=`grid-container2${item.id}`> using template string and set You CSS in the Block as well :) Similary for   <div class=`one-${item.id}`>1</div>

Comment: This is the logic that is coming to my mind right now :) This will work if you give it a thought :)